# Creating device (browser) fingerprint without JS fingerprint library

Tags: javascript

I need to create some unique ID for each device that is inserting a row in my database (creating post). I built this code based on googling and researching...

```js
function createFingerprint(string) {
  var hash = 0, i, chr;
  if (string.length === 0) return hash;
  for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    chr   = string.charCodeAt(i);
    hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0;
  }
  return hash;
};

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

var timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
var timezone_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
var graphics_card = gl.getParameter(gl.RENDERER);

console.log(createFingerprint(
    window.screen.availWidth + "x" +
    window.screen.availHeight + "_" +
    window.screen.colorDepth + "_" +
    navigator.userAgent + "_" +
    navigator.platform + "_" +
    navigator.language + "_" +
    navigator.hardwareConcurrency + "_" +
    navigator.cookieEnabled + "_" +
    timezone + "_" +
    timezone_offset + "_" +
    graphics_card
));
```

I know this code is not something that can my authentication rely on but can this be used to identify the device excluding the fact that the user can simply change their timezone and then the ID will be different. I wonder which of these variables can actually be the least changed so I can use only them to generate a device fingerprint? Also the hashing function that I'm currently using sucks a little. Is there a default `md5` JavaScript crypt functions that I can use instead of this function?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by doing this?  Are users authenticated beforehand? Is there a reason you are doing this on the client side rather than at the server?

Comment: Users are authenticated. I want to get some unique ID from the user's device and attach it to each post he insert into the database. Once I achieve this I want to keep track of whether multiple posts are inserted with different user_ids (accounts) and the same device ID or the reverse. Hopefully you understand me. I can't retrieve this information on the server side. I'm catching the information client side and pass it to the server side.